# combine mysql queries columnwise

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there anyway to combine mysql queries columnwise? I have below queries

```
select  count(ticket_id) as numInProgress from ost_ticket where status
 = 'in progress' and topic_id not in (select topic_id from ost_org_site_map)

 select  count(ticket_id) as numAssigned from ost_ticket where status =
 'open' and topic_id not in (select topic_id from ost_org_site_map)
```

and I am trying to get the result in the below format

```
---numInProgress | numAssigned---
            2    |     8
---------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use these as subqueries in a select statement, e.g.

```
SELECT ($statement1$),($statement2$)
```

or with your queries:

```
SELECT (select count(ticket_id) as numInProgress from ost_ticket where status = 'in progress' and topic_id not in (select topic_id from ost_org_site_map)) as numInProgress ,(select count(ticket_id) as numAssigned from ost_ticket where status = 'open' and topic_id not in (select topic_id from ost_org_site_map)) as numAssigned;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
SELECT (select count(ticket_id) as numInProgress 
        from ost_ticket where status = 'in progress' 
        and topic_id not in (select topic_id from ost_org_site_map)),
       (select count(ticket_id) as numAssigned 
        from ost_ticket where status = 'open' 
        and topic_id not in (select topic_id from ost_org_site_map));
```

ie combine both the queries to make a subquery in the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this:

```
SELECT sum(CASE OT.status when 'in progress' ,1,0) as numInProgress,
       sum(CASE OT.status when 'open' ,1,0) as numAssigned 
FROM ost_ticket OT
LEFT JOIN OST_ORG_SITE_MAP OSM
 ON OT.topic_Id =OSM.Topic_ID
WHERE OT.status in ('in progress', 'open')
  and OSM.Topic_ID is null
```

The left Join allows us to join OST_TICKET and OST_ORG_SITE_MAP on topic_Id.  When there is no topic ID in the site_map table then we have an equivalent to topic_Id not in...

we combined the status to only look for in progress and open and we use a case statement on status to determine what needs to be counted.  Since count will return values for 1 and 0, we needed to use sum to add up the 1's and 0's instead.