# mysql combine two queries into one query

Tags: mysql

I have two working queries. The first one selects the observed temperatures of a given month. The second selects the normal average for each day of that month.

```
SELECT data, Tmax, Tmin, Mitjana, Pluja 
FROM $estacio 
WHERE data BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-03-31'
```

---

```
SELECT data, round(avg(Mitjana),1) 
FROM $estacio 
WHERE month(data)='03' 
group by day(data), month(data) 
order by data
```

I'm trying to find the difference between the observed avg and the normal avg and insert into the first query as a new column. (Mitjana is mean)

Comment: possible duplicate of [combine mysql queries columnwise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729406/combine-mysql-queries-columnwise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply added the second query to the first one.

```
SELECT data, Tmax, Tmin, Mitjana, Pluja, (
  (SELECT NormalAvg FROM
    (SELECT data, round(avg(Mitjana),1) AS NormalAvg FROM $estacio
     WHERE month(data)='03'
     group by day(data), month(data) order by data) AS NormalAvgList
   WHERE NormalAvgList.data=est.data LIMIT 1)-Mitjana) AS Diff
  FROM $estacio AS est WHERE data BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-03-31'
```

Tested with [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a2f5d/12).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sadly, I can't extract the fifth column. I use mysql_fetch_array and $row[5] but only shows four columnns of data, the fifth is blank. I have tried $row['Diff'] with no luck.

Comment: I supose your answer is correct but I can't view the fifth column in my table. I insert rows in a var and print_r it. The result of Diff is blank in every row. Anybody knows why?